# Where is Katy Bowling?

Tags: wasteland-2

Robert Bowling in Ranger Citadel gives you a quest to deliver a letter to his sister Katy in Rail Nomad.  She doesn't seem to be there.  Both the bartender and shopkeeper know Robert Bowling (the former mentioning his serket habit), and have conversation entries for Katy Bowling, but those entries just say they don't know who she is.

Where is Katy Bowling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First railcar on the left with a green marking when you enter the main settlement area.

Comment: I looked in there and all I found was a dead librarian.